# How to count occurrences of Friday 13th

Tags: date-and-time

I would like to find a function that will count the number of times Friday 13th happens in a particular calendar year.

Does anybody have any hints ?

Thank you

Comment: I fell into a delightful rabbit hole of day-counting algorithms on Wikipedia. I wanted to leave a link to the Doomsday algorithm for mental calculation of the day of the week, for fun: [Doomsday rule on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule).

Comment: [Wolfram Challenges](https://challenges.wolfram.com/challenge/friday-the-13ths-in-a-year).

Comment: Sounds like one for the code golf boys and girls

Comment: Oh, of course they did it already: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69510/superstitious-programming

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Select[
 Table[DateObject@{2019, m, 13}, {m, 12}],
 DateString[#, "DayName"] === "Friday" &
]
```

> {Day: Fri 13 Sep 2019,Day: Fri 13 Dec 2019}

```
countFri13[year_Integer]:=Length @ Select[
 Table[DateObject@{year, m, 13}, {m, 12}],
 DateString[#, "DayName"] === "Friday" &
]
```

Answer (score 15):

I worked on this problem in 2015. Here is part on my notebook from that time.

A not so good algorithm.

```
friday13th[year_Integer] := 
  Select[DayName[#] === Friday &] @
    DateRange[DateObject[{year, 1, 13}], DateObject[{year, 12, 13}], {1, "Month"}]
```

A good algorithm.

```
friday13th[year_Integer] := 
  Select[DayName[#] === Friday &] @ Table[DateObject[{year, i, 13}], {i, 12}]
```

A better algorithm.

```
friday13th[year_Integer] := 
  Select[DayName[#] === Friday &] @ Array[DateObject[{year, #, 13}] &, 12]
```

Using the better algorithm, I got (at the time I created the notebook)

```
friday13th @ 2014
```

[image: 2014]

```
friday13th @ 2015
```

[image: 2015]

And for this year, I get

```
friday13th @ 2019
```

[image: 2019]

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @m_goldberg!

I ended up slightly modifying your code to find answer a halloween-themed question my 8 year old daughter had. "When will there be a Friday the 13th that happens on the full moon in October?"

```
friday13thfullmoon[year_Integer] := 
 Select[DayName[#] === Friday && DateValue[#, "Month"] === 10 && 
     MoonPhase[#, "Name"] === Entity["MoonPhase", "Full"] &]@
  Array[DateObject[{year, #, 13}] &, 12]
```

that's a little beyond her wolfram language capability (and I had to study yours for a few mins too), but she was able to understand the next step

```
Table[friday13thfullmoon[year], {year, 2020, 3020}] // Flatten
```

Turns out that in the next 1000 years it only happens three times!

[image: list of dates]